# Тип \"string\" не может быть назначен для типа \"number\"

Tags: typescript, typescript-типы

Из заголовка казалось бы сразу становится понятно почему возникает ошибка в моем TypeScript скрипте. Но..

Ошибка возникает когда пробую такую конструкцию после добавления "**.toFixed(2)**":

```
topprice = openOrders[item].price.toFixed(2)
```

также пробовал

```
topprice = Number(openOrders[item].price).toFixed(2)
```

Вывод кода:

```
let topprice = 0, topsize = 0, lowprice=0, lowsize=0
console.log(typeof topprice,' ',topprice,' ',typeof openOrders[item].price,' ',openOrders[item].price)
```

Даёт результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть получается что типы в обоих случаях - **Number**

Конструкция **openOrders[item]** имеет следующий вид одного элемента:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня не получается понять в чем проблема, особенно учитывая что оба типа переменных к которым обращаюсь - **Number**.

Comment: `toFixed` всегда возвращает строку, а число `37.8` невозможно задать точно из-за технических ограничений компьютеров

Comment: Понял. Решение оказалось простым, просто скобку переставил:
Number(openOrders[item].price.toFixed(2))

Comment: пожалуйста, напишите ответ на свой вопрос, иначе в существовании вопроса нет смысла

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение было простым, вместо:

```
topprice = openOrders[item].price.toFixed(2)
topprice = Number(openOrders[item].price).toFixed(2)
```

Пишем:

```
topprice = Number(openOrders[item].price.toFixed(2))
```

Так как первые две строки - идентичны.

1. `openOrders[item].price` - число, но после конвертации `toFixed` - становится строкой
2. число конвертируется в число и в конце конвертируется `toFixed` в строку

Поэтому правильно решение все выражение (которое будет в итоге строкой) поместить полностью в функцию `Number(...)`.

И по итогу число, которое мы пытаемся обрезать `toFixed` сначала конвертируется из числа в строку, а потом мы его обратно конвертируем в число.